# Need to convert points to polygons of a specific size, using the point as the center of the polygon

Tags: arcmap

I have a large collection of aerial photos with no georeferencing other than the Lat/Long location of the camera. Georeferencing them invididually is not an option (too much time, too many photos, some are oblique, some vertical). I need to automatically generate some kind of approximate polygonal footprint of each photo. I was thinking there must be some way to auto-generate a rectangle from a point layer using the point as the center and using numbers in the attribute fields as the dimensions. Or, barring that, just generating a circle at each point using an attribute as the diameter.

I'm using Arcview 9.3.1.

Comment: I can think of some ways to do this in autocad map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Import your photo points to a shapefile ([Make XY Event Layer](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Make%20XY%20Event%20Layer%20%28Data%20Management%29)).
2. Buffer the points to the appropriate size of your photos.
3. Install the [bounding containers toolbox](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14535) and run the extent tool.  This will create a north orientated square around the buffer.

Alternatively look at building a [raster catalog](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Create_Raster_Catalog/00170000008z000000/).  This may not be suitable if you have a lot of overlap, but will let you display the images without individual georeferencing.

Comment: Thanks! Step 3 is what I was missing. What we're trying to determine (very roughly) is how much coverage we have with these photos, creating squares around the buffer circles should do the trick.

Comment: I don't think this tool will work with 10.2.2.  Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

If you just have an approximate point of the center of each photo, just run the XY command with that input that then buffer the features.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think all you have to do is use the Lat/Lon; as you know it is the centroid, simply calculate the min/max x/y for your box, create a points list, and then Create the polygon.

X/Y is 341.5,61.5  So you could create a square of [343,60],[340,60],[340,63],[343,63]

So now you have a point list

```
point = arcpy.Point()
pointGeometryList = arcpy.Array()

linedata = [[343,60],[340,60],[340,63],[343,63]]

for coords in linedata:
    point.X = coords[0]
    point.Y = coords[1]
    pointGeometryList.add(point)

pointGeometryList.add(pointGeometryList.getObject(0))
polygon = arcpy.Polygon(pointGeometryList)
outFtrClass = r"C:\Dev\Scratch.gdb\MyPoly"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polygon , outFtrClass)
```

So all you have to do, is add logic to suck out your point values and create the linedata, and a new fc everytime.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered an awesome way in ArcGIS 10.4 to create rectangular buffer around your points! 
[image]

Following this picture, the **length *a* of the polygon  equals to 2-times the radius** (a = 2*r) of the buffer. Therefore, if you need a final rectangle of 1x1 km, the radius of the buffer is 500m.

Steps to follow:

1. create a Buffer (Buffer tool) of your desired size around your points
2. run Minimum bounding geometry Tool using "ENVELOPE" as desired geometry type
3. Voila you are all set!

[image]

More info and credits: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012502